# android searchview listview stopped unfortunately

Tags: android, listview, searchview

**i make an app on android studio, and the main activity contains search view and list view widgets,
and before including my search view , the app works fine , but after putting search view widget and it's formula , every time the app show this msg "unfortunately stop".
this is my script for the main activity java:**

---

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.SearchView;
```

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements                SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {
     ListView listView;
     SearchView mSearchView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
    setupSearchView();
    mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.operations);
    String[] values = new String[]
            { "Adjusted Body Weight",
                    "Body Mass Index",
                    "Creatinine Clearance",
                    "Dose Adjustment For Body Surface Area",
                    "Gestational Age",
                    "Ideal Body Weight For Pediatric",
                    "Norepinephrine",
                    "Pediatric Dosing: Oral Solid",
                    "Weight Based Dosage Calculator"
            };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            int itemPosition     = position;

            String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "You Choose "+itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            if (itemValue.toString()=="Creatinine Clearance")
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),CreatClear.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

            if (itemValue.toString()=="Adjusted Body Weight")
            {
                Intent intent = new       Intent(getApplicationContext(),AdjustedBodyWeight.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }


        }



    });

}



private void setupSearchView() {
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    mSearchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
    mSearchView.setQueryHint("Search Here For Your Operation");
}
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        listView.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        listView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}
}
```

and this is my main activity xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="#e7292a30">

<ListView
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="255dp"
    android:id="@+id/operations"
    android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar3"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Choose Your Operation:"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textColor="#60aaadbc"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar3"
    android:layout_above="@+id/ceo"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Developed By : "
    android:id="@+id/ceo"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ee1f1f22"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="46dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="hani"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ee1f1f22"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ProgressBar
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/progressBar5"
    android:layout_above="@+id/operations"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<SearchView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/search_view"
    android:layout_above="@+id/progressBar5"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and before adding the searchview every thing works fine, my script was:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.SearchView;



public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
ListView listView;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.operations);
    String[] values = new String[]
            {"Adjusted Body Weight",
                    "Body Mass Index",
                    "Creatinine Clearance",
                    "Dose Adjustment For Body Surface Area",
                    "Gestational Age",
                    "Ideal Body Weight For Pediatric",
                    "Norepinephrine",
                    "Pediatric Dosing: Oral Solid",
                    "Weight Based Dosage Calculator"
            };
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            int itemPosition = position;

            String itemValue = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "You Choose " + itemValue, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .show();
            if (itemValue.toString() == "Creatinine Clearance") {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CreatClear.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }

            if (itemValue.toString() == "Adjusted Body Weight") {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),     AdjustedBodyWeight.class);
                startActivity(intent);

            }


        }


    });

}


}
```

---

my logcat is :

```
http://s1.postimg.org/weuh2ffdr/main.png
```

---

so , what is the problem here and how i can solve it ?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: There is way too much going on here...way too much code.

Answer (score 0):

The official android developer site quotes "The Android logging system provides a mechanism for collecting and viewing system debug output. Logs from various applications and portions of the system are collected in a series of circular buffers, which then can be viewed and filtered by the logcat command. You can use logcat from an ADB shell to view the log messages.".

Please, refer to the LogCat for the exception. You may search the LogCat for a message which reads like "Exception caused by:". Hope, it helped.

Comment: i run it directly by mobile

Answer (score 0):

You must have a NullPointerException in 2 places:

```
setupSearchView();
mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
```

and

```
listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.operations);
```

That's because you're calling methods on `mSearchView` and `listView` before initializing them. All you have to do to fix them is to call them in reverse order:

```
mSearchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.search_view);
setupSearchView();
```

and

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.operations);
listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
```

Comment: i did what you write but the same thing, the app stopped

Comment: @hanisalama update your question with the error message you are getting.

Comment: @hanisalama because we are not psychics. Without an error message we can only guess.

Comment: can you find where is the probelm ?!, if i posted my logcat here

Comment: @hanisalama yes post the log cat. But on your question, not as a comment.

Comment: ok i will post it here as a comment firstly then i will update my question :)

Comment: @hanisalama remove this line:     `getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);`

Comment: i want to repute you but the system deny

Comment: @hanisalama well try later maybe. Glad you solved it.